# How to get column store object from 2 join tables in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 3 table with excatcly same columns names.
For this example lets say id,name,category, price.

when i extract data i got the desired data where each field renamed to source table. it is not so convinet and i want to extract data from same columns as arr of obj.

**currently query:**

```
SELECT 
     ta.name AS name_a,
     tb.name AS name_b,
     ta.price AS price_a,
     tb.price AS price_b,
     ta.category
FROM table_A ta
JOIN table_b tb on tb.id = ta.id
```

**Currently result**

| id | name_a | name_b | price_a | price_b | category |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | name1 | name2 | x | y | cats |
| 2 | name3 | name4 | m | n | cats |

**Desired result**

| id | names | prices | category |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | {name_a:name1,name_b:name2} | {price_a:x,price_b:y} | cats |
| 2 | {name_a:name3,name_b:name4} | {price_a:m,price_b:n} | cats |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT ta.id AS id
   , array['name_a:' || ta.name, 'name_b:' || tb.name] AS names
   , array['price_a:' || ta.price, 'price_b:' || tb.price] AS prices
   , ta.category AS category
FROM table_A ta
JOIN table_b tb on tb.id = ta.id
```

Answer (score 3):

Here it is using `jsonb_build_object` function.

```sql
SELECT id,
     jsonb_build_object('name_a', ta.name, 'name_b', tb.name) AS names,
     jsonb_build_object('price_a', ta.price, 'price_b', tb.price) AS prices,
     ta.category
FROM table_A ta JOIN table_b tb using(id);
```